# How to update project tree in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have my app open in Android studio.

I have created a directory tree in my app in CLI:

```
/react-native/AwesomeProject$ mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
```

But Android studio doesn't reflect this. I can see my new directories in cli, but not in Android Studio. How to refresh project directory tree in Android Studio? How to enable it to do so automatically?

Answer (score 1):

3 years later and I can't believe this hasn't been fixed yet.

So far, the only option is either to use the `File` > `Invalidate Caches and Restart`, or to just restart Android Studio (which is faster in my opinion).

Comment: yea it's a bit ridiculous honestly